# Unable to checkout document if "Require Check Out" is selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, check-out, onedrive

I am unable to check out a document from app on file explorer which has a setting "Require Check out" to be yes.

This Microsoft [reply](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/what-is-the-point-of-checking-inchecking-out-when/a1c49a5f-ef81-4e9f-a2ef-e65cc1a8d85d?rtAction=1615965919115) suggests there should be a yellow bar asking to checkout but I can't see that.

Please let know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Open your client application -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Protected View -> Uncheck all three options.

Then re-open document in the client application, check out will appear.

[image]

Comment: this didn't really solve the problem. I still can't see the Check Out bar. (Nor I can see the check out option from Info -> Manage Document)